How to render only the choose area
Is it possible to create a mesh with filter function in blender?
Assume i have a sphere, and i only want to render a rhombus area, the other part will be invisible.
Assume this is the sphere i want to render

and this is the filter like mesh

I want the rhombus area is visible and the other part become a Transparent film background(or maybe call invisible).


Hello, looks like you want to set the filter mesh to be set to holdout ?

Oh, yes, I just google search what is holdout, and it is what i need, Thank you
